# flutter amplify_storage_s3: ^1.6.0 upload file with targetIdentityId

Tags: flutter, amazon-s3

i am trying to upload file to s3 using the latest flutter SDK and there is no targetIdentityId suported

i am using amplify_storage_s3 to upload the file and i was using the old library that upload the file like this
 `await Amplify.Storage.uploadFile( local: file, key: "uploads/$fileName", options: S3UploadFileOptions( accessLevel: StorageAccessLevel.private, targetIdentityId: customUid, ), );`

and after update to latest library the upload file seems to be not suport the targetIdentityId

`await Amplify.Storage.uploadFile( localFile: awsFile, key: "uploads/$fileName", options: const StorageUploadFileOptions( accessLevel: StorageAccessLevel.private, ), ).result`

my question is there any way to send targetIdentityId when upload file using the latest sdk